# ​[revit] up for burnination

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) and [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) tags seem to mean the same thing as any question regarding coding and revit with have the revit-api tag and any question that deals with revit but not with coding seems off-topic.

[revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) 76
[revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) - [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) 55
[revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) - [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) 54
Total: 185

In total 130 questions are tagged as [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api)  and [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) as revit, looking at the first page almost all questions tagged as revit are also taged as revit-api. And the once that haven't been tagged as revit-api can easily be retaged as revit-api

Comment: 1) Something that would be helpful: some statistics, like - how many questions in each, and how many are tagged with one, and not the other. 2) It sounds from your description more like [tag:revit] needs to be burninated, rather than merged. 3) [I have a fever, and the only prescription, is more title puns.](http://www.hulu.com/watch/536145)

Comment: It's more like 2/3.

Comment: Title option: `Rev up for burninating [revit]` (Needs work, but it's still early)

Comment: @theB alright it will work for now.

Comment: Why not "[revit] up for burnination"?

Comment: PS - zero width space :)